# i18n translation with a different domain in .py files

Tags: python, internationalization, translation, plone

I'm a little confused on i18n translations in py files. I have a string where what needs to be translated is already in the plone domain in plone.pot so I want to specify the domain to be plone for that translation only. When I do the following, I get an error. And, this does get rendered in a page template so there's no need to call the translate function, is this correct?

```
    raise ValueError(_(u'Some string', domain='plone'))

    TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'domain'
```

How should this be done? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have two different message factories, i.e. where you do

```
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory('my.package')
```

you should be also instantiating the Plone one.

```
_p = MessageFactory('plone')
```

Then `_p('Contributors')` would give you the translated string.

Have a look [here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n/translating-text-in-code) too.

Comment: Are message factories named something other than _ found by i18ndude when updating .pot files?

Comment: @DavidGlick iirc you specify the domain you want to i18ndude

Comment: what about aquisition in Plone? if I just did _(u'Some string') and it wasn't found in my current app package, wouldn't it go and then try to find 'Some string' in Plone's (in plone.pot)? Would this work too?

Comment: @JCarter No, acquisition has absolutely nothing to do with i18n messages.